# Scraping HTML using R - xpathSApply

Tags: html, r, xpath, screen-scraping

I want to extract information from the below html code using their classes or xpathSapply.

I want to capture different information as a table, for example

- effectiveness as a column populated with 5 and Full comment

instead of

- the truncated one as a column populated with the full comment.

---

```
<div class="userPost">
<div class="postHeading clearfix">
  <div class="conditionInfo">
                Condition: Condition in which Stomach Acid is Pushed Into the Esophagus</div>
  <div class="date">8/12/2014 12:27:53 PM</div>
</div>
<p class="reviewerInfo">Reviewer: Believer, 35-44 Female  on Treatment for 2 to less than 5 years (Patient) </p>
<div id="ctnStars">
  <div class="catRatings firstEl clearfix">
    <p class="category">Effectiveness</p>
    <p class="inlineRating starRating"><span class="current-rating" style="width: 100%">
        Current Rating: 5</span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="catRatings clearfix">
    <p class="category">Ease of Use</p>
    <p class="inlineRating starRating"><span class="current-rating" style="width: 100%">
        Current Rating: 5</span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="catRatings lastEl clearfix">
    <p class="category">Satisfaction</p>
    <p class="inlineRating starRating"><span class="current-rating" style="width: 100%">
        Current Rating: 5</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
<p id="comTrunc1" class="comment"><strong>Comment: </strong><br>Most excellent! I tried several different rx&#39;s to help with my acid problem and none were as effective as Nexium. After being on it for 3 months I stopped because that was how long my doc thought it would take to heal me.  I stopped taking it and boom, the pain was back.  Got back on Nexium and am staying on it. Such relief was unexpected.</p>
<p id="comFull1" class="comment" style="display:none"><strong>Comment:</strong><br>Most excellent! I tried several different rx&#39;s to help with my acid problem and none were as effective as Nexium. After being on it for 3 months I stopped because that was how long my doc thought it would take to heal me.  I stopped taking it and boom, the pain was back.  Got back on Nexium and am staying on it. Such relief was unexpected.<br><a onclick="toggle('comTrunc1'); toggle('comFull1');return false;" href="#">Hide Full Comment</a></p>
<div class="actionLinks clearfix">
  <p class="helpful">4
                        people

                found this review helpful.<br>
                Was this review helpful?  <span id="513102_Vote"><a href="#" onclick="return FoundHelpFul('8cbc5bf1-4f86-48e4-ac0f-5b3085949a2a', 513102, true)">Yes</a> | <a href="#" onclick="return FoundHelpFul('8cbc5bf1-4f86-48e4-ac0f-5b3085949a2a', 513102, false)">No</a></span></p><a class="reportAbuse" href="#" onclick="showPopWin('ReportAbuse.aspx?reviewid=513102&amp;userid=8cbc5bf1-4f86-48e4-ac0f-5b3085949a2a',400,160,null, false); return false;">Report This Post</a></div>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. So: what code have you tried? did it break? if so - what was the error message? At S/O we prefer to help you with what you've had a go with, rather than writing it for you  so show us what you've got :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me what you are doing, but here is a start.  If this is not in the direction you want, please edit your question after you try something along these lines (and include your code).  Assuming "url" is the website url from which you got the HTML code you provided, try something like this:

```
library(xml)
doc <- htmlTreeParse(url) # reads into the object doc the contents of the url

data <- xpathSApply(doc, "//div[@id = 'ctnStars']//[[@class = 'category']", xmlValue, trim = TRUE) # to extract the value of that node ("Effectiveness")
```